# Discriminate Sybase ASE from Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sap-ase

I have some applications that run either on Sybase ASE 15.0.3 or on Microsoft SQL Server 2008r2. The 2 servers have the same content.
Normally everything works, but in some cases I want to know which server is being used.
Is there a query that will give different results on Sybase and Microsoft, so that I can know in my application which server I am connected to?
I don't think it matters but I program in PHP/Apache/Linux/FreeTDS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select @@Version` will tell you what you're running on.